Can I say "I'm not now" to mean "I'm not keeping a pet now" when the asker used the present simple earlier?

Q: Do you keep a pet?
A: No, I don't. I don't feel responsible enough for it. If I kept a pet, I would want to give it proper attention, but my current lifestyle doesn't allow for that. So I'm not.

Would the listener understand that I meant "I'm not keeping a pet" if I only said "I'm not"? If not, does adding "now" as in "I'm not now" make it right?

"I'm not" isn't a proper answer to "Do you keep a pet?" But in the soup of conversation, separated by so many carrots, bits of onion, and beans, as it is there, the lack of agreement would go unnoticed, and the listener would be likely to parse it as simply reinforcing "No, I don't".   now doesn't make it proper. The question has Do.

Certainly you would be understood. It's a little clumsy, and adding "now" doesn't make it better, but it's the kind of sentence a native speaker might produce off-the-cuff.
However, you're not entirely correct about the reason. The fragment wouldn't necessarily have to match the question, as long as it matched something preceding it.

Q: Do you keep a pet?
A: No, I don't. I don't feel responsible enough for it. If I were keeping a pet, I would want to give it proper attention, but my current lifestyle doesn't allow for that. So I'm not.

Changing one of the verbs to agree with the fragment (while retaining the one that agrees with the question) is enough to turn this into a well-formed reply.

I don't think it's clumsy. As A UK English speaker it seems pretty standard - it would be used for any long-term state such as owning a pet, doing a job, living somewhere, etc. Example: "Are you still living in Brighton?" "No, I'm not now, I had to move." The alternative is to use "do" which sounds a bit weird in such contexts, IMO. Might be personal opinion though.

@StuartF The question is about tense agreement between the question and answer. Your example has agreement, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to prove.

Yes, this is very common.
If someone asks you a question, it is common to answer with something that is not a complete sentence. Like if someone asks, "What is your brother's name?", most English speakers would answer simply "George", not, "My brother is named George".
"I'm not" is, in fact, a complete sentence. It has a subject, "I", and a predicate "am not". But by itself, if you don't know the question, it is meaningless. If someone just walked up to you and began a conversation by saying "I'm not", your likely response would be, "Not what?"
But in response to the question, "Are you keeping a pet?", if you say, "I'm not", the asker knows exactly what you mean. I guess you could say it is short for, "I am not keeping a pet."
I'd quibble that if someone asked, "Do you keep a pet?", the appropriate response would be "I don't", that is, "I don't keep a pet", and not "I'm not". If they asked, "Are you a pet owner?", then "I'm not" would be appropriate.
